# Invariant Generation Constraint-based approach

Tags: system, transition, z3, integer-arithmetic

I have been read the paper "Constraint-Based Linear-Relations Analysis" from "Sriram Sankaranarayanan, Henny B. Sipma, and Zohar Mann" to check fixpoint equations arising from abstract interpretation by applying Farkas Lemma in a Given template inequality with unknown coefficients, which computes constraints on the values of the coefficients, such that substituting any solution back into the template yields a valid invariant relationship.

I have Followed example 1 (on that paper)
`Let V = {x, y}` and `L = { 0 }`. Consider the transition system shown below. Each transition models a concurrent process, that updates the variables x, y automatically.

```
Θ = (x = 0 ∧ y = 0)
T = {τ1 , τ2 }
τ1 = <l0 , l0 , [x' = x + 2y ∧ y' = 1 − y]>
τ2 = <l0, l0 , [x' = x + 1 ∧ y' = y + 2]>
```

I have encoded Initiation, by using Farkas Lemma (example 2 on that paper) as well consecution (through transitions τ1 and τ2).

The authors say:

> We fix a linear transition system `Π` with variables `{x1 , . . . , xn }`, collectively referred to as x. The system is assumed to have a single location to simplify the presentation. The template assertion at location , is `α(c) = c1 x1 + · · · + cn xn + d ≥ 0`. The coefficient variables `{c1 , . . . , cn , d}` are collectively referred to as c. The system's transitions are `{τ1 , . . . , τm }`, where `τi : , , ρi`. The initial condition is denoted by Θ. The system in Example 1 will be used as a running example to illustrate the presented ideas.

I have reached the overall constraint obtained by the conjunction of the constraints obtained from initiation and consecution for each transition (example 4 on that paper).

At that point I guess it is possible to solve the constraint by encoding all of that in a solve like `Z3`.
In fact I did that by encoding linear arithmetic directly into `Z3`:

```
(define-sort MyType () Int)
(declare-const myzero MyType)
(declare-const mi1 MyType)
(declare-const mi2 MyType)
(declare-const c1 MyType)
(declare-const c2 MyType)
(declare-const d MyType)
(assert (= myzero 0))
;initiation
    (assert (>= d 0) )
;transition 1
(assert (and 
    (= (- (* mi1 c1) c1) 0)
    (= (- (+ (* mi1 c2) c2) (* 2 c1) ) 0)
    (<= (- (- (* mi1 d) d) c2) 0)
    (>= mi1 0)
))
;transition 2
(assert (and 
    (= (- (* mi2 c1) c1) 0)
    (= (- (* mi2 c2) c2) 0)
    (<= (- (- (- (* mi2 d) d) c1) (* 2 c2) ) 0)
    (>= mi2 0)
))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

I guess I am not doing well once I have not figured out any inductive invariant at location `l0` through `c1`, `c2`, ..., `cn`, `d` as an individual (`o` range) values.

Z3 has answered me zero for all coefficients:

```
sat
(model 
    (define-fun mi2 () Int 0)
    (define-fun c2 () Int 0)
    (define-fun mi1 () Int 0)
    (define-fun c1 () Int 0)
    (define-fun d () Int 4)
    (define-fun myzero () Int 0)
)
```

I have tried to found examples related with, but until now no luck to get it.

Comment: Here is the link of the cited paper: [link]http://theory.stanford.edu/~sipma/papers/sas04.pdf

Comment: Your SMT problem is not in linear real arithmetic: you're multiplying unknowns together (e.g. `(* mi2 c1)`) and the unknowns are integer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are doing correctly in your Z3 encoding, you are indeed
getting correct but trivial invariants like 0 <= 4.

To get interesting invariants, I suggest adding constraints like c1 <> 0 to see if the solver gives you something interesting back.

Our work was done long before Z3 existed: we used the solver REDLOG as part of REDUCE, which is still available. Welcome to email me with your queries.

Best,
Sriram